# Parsing as temporaryFile from request.body

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I need to parse out the body of a POST request as a temporary file. On the Scala play docs, it says use

```
Action(parse.temporaryFile) {request => request.body.moveTo(new File("/tmp/picture/uploaded"))}
```

but I was wondering if I could extract it from just a regular request body. The other parsers can be used as `request.body.asMultipartFormData` or `request.body.asFormUrlEncoded`, but I could not find any similar usage for parse.temporaryFile. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***asMultipartFormData***

```
    req.body.asMultipartFormData.map(mfd =>
        for(tmpFile <- mfd.files) {
            ... your processing
        }
    )
```